# BSOD Critical Structure Corruption on Win10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I changed the ram but the problem is not solved

**Error code in event viewer:** 0x00000109 (0xa39fd4e448c045cd, 0xb3b6e16a9b43ab35, 0x00000000000001a0, 0x0000000000000007).

### **Minidump File 1**
Debugging Details:

PG_MISMATCH:  40000

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x109

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:
ffffda88`a0f09df8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000109 a3a01de3`ff28d9e0 b3b72a6a`51ab2ed8 00000000`000001a0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
fffff802219981fe-fffff80221998201  4 bytes - nt!MiFreeUltraMapping+32

```
[ a0 7d fb f6:60 fe fc f9 ]
fffff802219d96c0-fffff802219d96c3  4 bytes - nt!KiMarkBugCheckRegions+428 (+0x414c2)


[ ff d0 0f 1f:e8 1b ac 63 ]
```

8 errors : !nt (fffff802219981fe-fffff802219d96c3)

SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID:  BAD_STACK

Followup: MachineOwner

### Minidump File 2 Debugging Details:
Debugging Details:

PG_MISMATCH:  40000

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x109

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:
ffff8c89`32d90e28 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000109 a3a00adb`ed19e564 b3b71762`3f9c3a5c 00000000`000001a0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
fffff804767981fe-fffff80476798201  4 bytes - nt!MiFreeUltraMapping+32

```
[ a0 7d fb f6:c0 a3 47 8f ]
```

4 errors : !nt (fffff804767981fe-fffff80476798201)

SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID:  BAD_STACK

Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: `I changed the ram` - what made you think the RAM was the issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x109---critical-structure-corruption
3. A hardware corruption occurred. For example, the kernel code or data could have been stored in memory that failed

Comment: well, I guess you've ruled out RAM ... tell us more about the rest of the system. Motherboard, CPU, GPU, any BIOS tweaks you've made ...

Comment: System was working fine with hdd(win10). The person using this computer last week bought a new ssd and installed a new win 10 Enterprise on this ssd. After this installation bsod problem was occuring. I am not sure about drivers properly installed. Should I do a clean o.s. install again?

Comment: Sure, why not. Nothing to lose